# How do I make a method that uses the object name in c#?

Tags: c#, object, methods

Say I have a class called `Enabler`
I make an instance of the class like I'd normally do (in semi-pseudo c# code)

```
bool cond;
Enabler enable = new Enabler(cond);
```

the problem arises when I call the Enabler's method called `Enable`, it's not so much of a problem as it is horribly verbose

```
enable.Enable(/*some code to enable*/);
```

the real problem arises when I do this:

```
Enabler disable = new Enabler(!cond); //reverse condition

disable.Enable(/*some code to disable*/); //this makes no sense semantically
```

so I'm looking for a way to do something like this:

```
Enabler enable = new Enabler(cond);
Enabler disable = new Enabler(!cond);

// then simply call the method by the object name like this:
enable(/*something to enable*/); //uses the object name as the method name
disable(/*something to disable*/);
```

this makes loads more sense semantically than saying `disable.Enable`

is there any way to do this at all?

just like it's possible to do a `this[]`, is it also possible to make a `this()` of sorts?

Comment: What is the parameter type of `Enable()`?

Comment: It would make more sense to have 2 methods, 1 for enable and 1 for disable. Then with sensible naming you could have: `BooleanTest.Enable(/*Enable Something*/);` and `BooleanTest.Disable(/*Disable Something*/);` The Test host would then always have both methods with one method being the inverse test.

Comment: @JamesB no, because it's supposed to toggle when `cond` changes, just like an if skips code if the starting condition is false, the `Enabler` skips code if the condition in the constructor is false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just call the method `Activate` or `Execute`

and have two instances

```
Enabler enable= new Enabler(cond);
Enabler disable = new Enabler(!cond);

enable.Activate()

disable.Activate()
```

Also I feel enabler is a bad class name.

Your class handles both Enabling and Disabling it is not clear from your class name what it does.

You should name it `StatusChanger` or whatever is appropriate for your application.

Also why don't you just have two methods, `enable` and `disable`?

Comment: sounds reasonable, I thought of using `Invoke` instead of `Activate`, but I guess that works too

Comment: as for not having the 2 methods is because it's supposed to switch when the boolean used in the constructor changes, I know I'm supposed to use functions for something like that, but the example uses pseudo code anyway...

Answer (score 3):

afaik it's not possible to do something like this. But if you can Disable and Enable with your "Enabler" class, "Enabler" probably is not the right name anyway.

What about "Toggler" or something more verbose?

Edit: @Nahum's answer is also a good hint. To have well maintainable code, you should change both imo.

Comment: yeah thanks for the naming idea but it was just an example class after all